# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' react gatsby webapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

**

> React Gatsby web app: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

**

I am getting this error while running the app. This page is having a button event handler. look at this code given below.

Coursecart.js page.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import Heading from "../Reuseable/Heading"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const getCategory = items => {
  let holditems = items.map(items => {
    return items.node.category
  })
  let holdCategories = new Set(holditems)
  let categories = Array.from(holdCategories)
  categories = ["all", ...categories]
  return categories
}

export default class Coursecart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      courses: props.courses.edges,
      mycourses: props.courses.edges,
      mycategories: getCategory(props.courses.edges),
    }
  }

  cateClicked = category => {
    let keepItsafe = [...this.state.courses]
    if (category === "all") {
      this.setState(() => {
        return { mycourses: keepItsafe }
      })
    } else {
      let holdMe = keepItsafe.filter(node => {
        return node.category === category
      })
      this.setState(() => {
        return { mycourses: holdMe }
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="py-5">
        <div className="container">
          <Heading title="Courses" />
          <div className="row my-3">
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto text-center">
              {this.state.mycategories.map((category, index) => {
                return (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-info m-3 px-3"
                    key={index}
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.cateClicked(category)
                    }}
                  >
                    {category}
                  </button>
                )
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.mycourses.map(({ node }) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={node.id}
                  className="col-11 col-md-6 d-flex my-3 mx-auto"
                >
                  <Img fixed={node.image.fixed} />
                  <div className="flex-grow-1 px-3">
                    <div className="d-flex">
                      <h6 className="mb-0">{node.title}</h6>
                      <h6 className="mb-0 text-success ml-3">$ {node.price}</h6>
                    </div>
                    <p className="text-muted">
                      <small>{node.description.description}</small>
                    </p>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-warning snipcart-add-item"
                      data-item-id={node.id}
                      data-item-name={node.title}
                      data-item-price={node.price}
                      data-item-url="https://https://rgecom.netlify.app/"
                      data-item-image={node.image.fixed.src}
                    >
                      Join Now
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to run this code, because it clearly depends on a complex prop value (`courses`) as well as external modules whose source code is not present. I'd recommend hollowing-out this component and just logging the props as strings to confirm that the input values are precisely what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly caused by attempting to parse an XHR response as JSON, when the body actually contains HTML.

That is frequently caused when the request is wrong: a misspelled path component or an unsupported method. Some HTTP server frameworks are configured by default to return a very basic HTML error page for unmatched routes.

So, if you've got a typo in your fetch, and the target server is using the default unmatched-route response, but your code assumes the response will be JSON, you will get this exact error.

Try running this snippet in your JS console, and I bet you'll get the same error:

```js
JSON.parse('<!DOCTYPE html>')
```

Comment: **I've done logging the props in the string but there is no lag in the props. I've done cache clear for npm also but it still there.do you have any other solution for this? Thanks sir, for the quick response but I still can not solve this error**